# Mule ESB - Specify JMS Queue Name as a property

Tags: mule

I want to set the queuename as a property key in the Mulesoft ESB JMS Connector. My queue names will be different based on the environment. I have different property files that are environment specific. I want to set the queue name, that is environment specific, based on a property value.

Currently I have this:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="q_Test" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="q_Test"/>
```

However I need functionality similar as below:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue=<property-key> connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="q_Test"/>
```

and I want to use the value for  from a properties file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any problem in setting queue name from properties file  ... However I am unable to see your configuration here .Pls make sure your code is visible and put under code block

Answer (score 1):

Queue names are specified as part of the JMS inbound endpoint, and there is no restriction on the use of a property placeholder there, you may simply do:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${your.property}" />
```

And use one the various techniques to load different property placeholder configurers from different environments.